# Is there an automated way to change the Compatibility Mode of all executables in a folder tree and also make these Run as Administrator?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, vbscript

I need to change all executables inside an EDA suite that is installed in a Windows 10 machine to run in Windows 7 compatibility mode and also make these Run as Administrator.
There are hundreds of small .EXE's and doing it manually will take forever!
Thanks.

Comment: Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/af3d4892-8e08-437f-ba08-5323489f6729/how-to-set-run-as-administrator-property-to-any-exe-thru-code?forum=vbgeneral help?

Comment: It led to https://www.verboon.info/2011/03/running-an-application-as-administrator-or-in-compatibility-mode/ which is really helpful..!!

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.

```
FOR /r %%i IN (*.exe) DO (
   @echo %%~fi
   reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~fi" /d "WIN7RTM RUNASADMIN"
)
```